# How to make InputGetKeyDown last more than a frame?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So this Script summons a UI if I press "E" key. The problem is as soon as I pressed it, it immediately disappears because it was supposed to be a single frame. How to make it last longer like for 5 seconds?

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit, rayLength, layerMaskInteract.value))
{
    if(hit.collider.CompareTag("Object"))
     {
         raycastedObj = hit.collider.gameObject;

         if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
         {
             Debug.Log("done");
             LaptopUI.SetActive(true);                     
         }
         else
         {
             LaptopUI.SetActive(false); 
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: just take a look at the [Input functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html), it also offers the GetKey and GetKeyUp function. Also if you want it to stay active for a specific Time you could use  a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html), that activates and deactivates the UI element

Answer (score 2):

You're correct about the source of your issue: You are checking every frame whether or not the key is pressed. The frame after you release the "e" key, the laptop UI will close.

You have two clear options to solve this problem.

1. Add a toggle.

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit, rayLength, layerMaskInteract.value))
        {
            if(hit.collider.CompareTag("Object"))
            {
                raycastedObj = hit.collider.gameObject;

                if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("toggled");
                    LaptopUI.SetActive(!LaptopUI.activeSelf);//Invert the value
                }
            }
        }
```

2. Keep track of the time the window has been open.

First, add a variable outside of function scope to hold the desired closing time.

```
    private float CloseAtTime;
```

Then set our closing time when we open the Laptop UI.

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit, rayLength, layerMaskInteract.value))
        {
            if(hit.collider.CompareTag("Object"))
            {
                raycastedObj = hit.collider.gameObject;

                if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("opened");
                    CloseAtTime = Time.time + 5f;//Close around 5 seconds from now.
                    LaptopUI.SetActive(true);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    if(LaptopUI.activeSelf && Time.time >= CloseAtTime)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("closed");
                        LaptopUI.SetActive(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you and I tried the second method and it worked! but the problem arises when the UI refuses to disappear unless I return near the object position (rayLength) instead of just walking away.

Comment: If you use the second method, you'll need to add a check outside of the physics raycast then. If you invert the order and check for the key BEFORE performing the physics raycast, it'll be an easier problem to solve. Honestly, I'd personally use an anonymous async function rather than keeping track in the update function. LeanTween has a good method for doing this, and you can add Async/Await functionality to Unity through the official package.

Answer (score 0):

Input.GetKeyDown() won't last you more than a frame ever. if you want it to behave like a menu so by pressing E the UI appears, and when a second press happens it disappears, you should just do the following:

```
     if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
     {
         Debug.Log("done");
         LaptopUI.SetActive(!LaptopUI.activeSelf);                     
     }
```

If you want it to last for a given time you could use a coroutine or your own timer, I'll show you how to do the coroutine.

```
public GameObject LaptopUI; //Set this in the inspector, you need to have this game object declared outside your function so the coroutine can access it.
void yourFunction()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit, rayLength, layerMaskInteract.value))
    {
        if(hit.collider.CompareTag("Object"))
         {
             raycastedObj = hit.collider.gameObject;
    
             if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
             {
                 StartCoroutine(CloseUI(5f));                  
             }
         }
    }
}

public IEnumerator CloseUI(float time)
{
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
   LaptopUI.SetActive(false);
}
```

I didn't have the chance to test the code but if you get any errors, let me know and I shall fix my answer.